# Need help regarding chinese captcha

Tags: translation

I'm trying to play a chinese game that I have played before. Back then, only drag captchas were required. Now they require numbering. Can someone help me please? I cannot login without doing so.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please click in order: 节茧

Look for 节茧 on the picture and click them in order